# graph with a cut vertex contains a bridge

Tags: graph-theory

Give a counter example to each of the following:
 (a) G is a connected graph with a cut-vertex, then G contains a bridge. 
(b) G is a tree if and only if it contains no cycle.

Comment: What are your thoughts about this?  You could at least start with defining the terms used in the statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), take two cycles and join them at a vertex.

[image]

For (b), David's example of a forest with more than 1 tree in it works, as trees are connected by definition.

Answer (score 0):

For $(a)$, there are no counterexamples. this is a consequence of vertex connectivity being less than or equals to the edge connectivity.

For $(b)$, if we don't assume $G$ connected, any forest (union of trees) with more than one component will work. Note the definition of tree is a connected graph with no cycles.

Comment: For (a), you can have cut-vertices without bridges. For example if vertex connectivity is 1 and edge connectivity is 2, you have a cut-vertex but no bridge.